# Redirect to Facebook login URL using PHP SDK in Kohana 3.3

Tags: redirect, facebook-php-sdk, kohana, facebook-login, kohana-3.3

I have a controller handling user registration using FB data:

```
 if ($this->isLogged()) {
        try {
            $apiObject = $this->_fb->api('/me');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            $apiObject = null;
            throw $e;
        }
    } else {
        HTTP::redirect($this->getLoginUrl());
    }
```

But redirect is not working it just redirects back to the page at which was this code triggered.

How can I redirect user to FB in Kohana 3.3 so he can log in?

*getLoginUrl() method returns:*

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123456&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.test.com%2Fregistration-user%3Fh_module%3Duser%26h_action%3Dregister_fb%26h_secure%3Deffeeeff&state=fdsfdfdfdf&display=popup&scope=email
```

Comment: Did you change Kohana's exception handling functionality or is there a try-catch surrounding that block of code that could prevent the Exception thrown by HTTP::Redirect() reaching Kohana's Exception handler? Also, does the string returned by $this->getLoginUrl() contain '://'?

Comment: No, exception handling functionality is not changed (at least I am not aware of it) and there is no try-catch block surrounding this code. I edited question and added full URL.